# How to divide the Button control from the listbox

Tags: c#, wpf, button, data-binding, listbox

I have a **ListBox** control in the **WPF** form which contains the Button control.

Button control has the `int values` like 65.

I want to display seven buttons which is divided of the 65.

Also I want to put the content on the button which says `1 - 10, 11 - 20, 21 - 30, etc..` and  65 value comes from the database.

Comment: And what did you have besides idea?

Comment: Still not clear, try to explain with an image.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ListBox.ItemTemplate to create the listbox which contains the buttons.
Here is the sample which I have created which binds the ObservalbleCollection as the ItemSource of the listbox:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding ListDiv}">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel>
                    <Button Content="{Binding}"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

The .cs File for the same is:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private ObservableCollection<string> listDiv;
    public ObservableCollection<string> ListDiv
    {
        get { return listDiv; }
        set
        {
            listDiv = value;
            OnNotifyPropertyChanged("ListDiv");
        }
    }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = this;
        GetList();
    }

    private void GetList()
    {
        ListDiv = new ObservableCollection<string>();
        ListDiv.Add("1-10");
        ListDiv.Add("2-20"); 
        ListDiv.Add("3-30"); 
        ListDiv.Add("4-40");
        ListDiv.Add("5-50");
        ListDiv.Add("6-60");
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void OnNotifyPropertyChanged(string S)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(S));
    }
}
```

You can use your own logic part to Get the Observable Collection in GetList() Method.

**Don't Forget to set the DataContext of the Class.**

Hope this will help you, Thank you.

Comment: Thank you for the comment but i am using MVVM architecture.. i forgot ask in the Question..